# GLIBCXX in libstdc++.so.6 on RHEL 7.2 for Rocket.Chat

Tags: rocket.chat

I have installed Rocket.Chat on RHEL 7.2 using the manual procedure available at:
https://rocket.chat/docs/installation/manual-installation/centos

I am getting the below error in system logs:

```
Jan  7 16:39:20 ibmsitldct02 rocketchat: Error: /lib64/libstdc++.so.6: version `GLIBCXX_3.4.20' not found (required by /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/bin/linux-x64-57/fibers.node)
```

This is what I have on the server in terms of libstdc library:

```
$ ls -lrt /lib64/libstdc*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 830776 Mar  5  2015 /lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 991616 Oct 30 06:39 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     18 Dec 19 12:26 /lib64/libstdc++.so.5 -> libstdc++.so.5.0.7
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     19 Jan  2 14:12 /lib64/libstdc++.so.6 -> libstdc++.so.6.0.19
```

Unfortunately, version 3.4.20 isn't contained v6.0.19 I have got on the server:

```
$ strings /lib64/libstdc++.so.6.0.19 |grep GLIBCXX
GLIBCXX_3.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.1
GLIBCXX_3.4.2
GLIBCXX_3.4.3
GLIBCXX_3.4.4
GLIBCXX_3.4.5
GLIBCXX_3.4.6
GLIBCXX_3.4.7
GLIBCXX_3.4.8
GLIBCXX_3.4.9
GLIBCXX_3.4.10
GLIBCXX_3.4.11
GLIBCXX_3.4.12
GLIBCXX_3.4.13
GLIBCXX_3.4.14
GLIBCXX_3.4.15
GLIBCXX_3.4.16
GLIBCXX_3.4.17
GLIBCXX_3.4.18
GLIBCXX_3.4.19
GLIBCXX_DEBUG_MESSAGE_LENGTH
```

Yum gives the message that it is upto date:

```
$ sudo yum install libstdc++.so.6
Plugin "search-disabled-repos" requires API 2.7. Supported API is 2.6.
Loaded plugins: langpacks, product-id, rhui-lb, subscription-manager
This system is not registered to Red Hat Subscription Management. You can use subscription-manager to register.
Package libstdc++-4.8.5-36.el7.i686 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

Is there a way around this error?

Warm Regards,
Ankit

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved using the workaround listed for the bug. Basically, by rebuilding node-gyp for my OS
https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/issues/9167

```
npm install -g node-gyp
cd /opt/Rocket.Chat/programs/server/node_modules/fibers/
node-gyp rebuild
cp build/Release/fibers.node bin/linux-x64-57/fibers.node
systemctl start rocketchat.service
```